# Ubuntu Touch running on Fairphone - are there agreements?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I bought a Fairphone (http://www.fairphone.com) because I've read that it should be open for different OS, e.g. Ubuntu Touch. Now I would like to know, if Canonical will use that chance to provide Ubuntu Touch on that hardware?

People that are interested in fair hardware are normally more open for ideas like open software, so that could be a good anchor to make Ubuntu Touch more public.

Comment: This is a strong opinion and I am not sure everyone would agree: "People that are interested in fair hardware are normally more open for ideas like open software"

Comment: It appears to say on their site that they're "working with Ubuntu, and FireFox (sic.)" to get those OSes running on the Fairphone

Answer (score 1):

For now both the fairphone and Ubuntu Touch are unfinished products, so it's to early say anything.

Fairphone wants their phone to be as open as possible. They also partnered-up with Canonical. I'd be surprised if there won't be a Fairphone-Ubuntu-Touch release.

> "We are planning to launch the phone with root access for the user
>   (rootable), so they can decide for themselves which operating system
>   they want to install after some hard coding. At this point, we really
>   need the support of open-source communities – people who develop for
>   Firefox and Ubuntu – to help us optimize our device for these
>   operating systems."
>   - Fairphone.com